# uv_run keeps returning success forever

Tags: libuv

I tried to run the following code and the function keeps returning 0 after the first receive:

```
while (true)
{
    int res = uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_ONCE);
    if (res == 0)
        printf("ok\n");
}
```

Is there a way to reset the loop, so that it will return 0 on the second receive and won't stuck on success from the first one ?

Answer (score 1):

> uv_run keeps returning success forever

In this case, 0 doesn't mean *success*.
As mentioned [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/loop.html) for `uv_run` (emphasis mine):

> UV_RUN_ONCE: **Poll for i/o once**. Note that this function blocks if there are no pending callbacks. **Returns zero when done (no active handles or requests left)**, or non-zero if more callbacks are expected (meaning you should run the event loop again sometime in the future).

If there exists at least one callback, the function call won't block and it will execute them, then it will return. It polls for I/O only once, it is meant for that and you are asking - *is it possible to have it working differently from what it is meant for?* Well, no.
Use `UV_RUN_DEFAULT` instead and close all the handles when you have finished with them, so that the loop ends and the function call returns.

Comment: Hi skypjack and thank you for the answer. I am trying to research libuv, so it will fit best for gaming architecture. I am trying to call it every frame so it wont block the UI. is this the correct way ? to close the handlers and init them once again every frame or there is some other way ?

Comment: @Gabrielkotev No, if you intend to have long operations, simply don't close them. As an example, a TCP handle that echoes on a port should stay up and running as long as you want to offer the service. I'd suggest you to read the documentation of libuv, everything is explained quite well.